# How to disable multiple cursors in sublime2?

Tags: sublimetext2

How do I disable the multiple cursor feature in Sublime text 2? I googled, but found only videos on how to use it, not how to not use it..

Comment: just don't use this feature, why do you want to disable it?

Comment: It would sometimes turn on b/c I think I press wrong buttons and I end up adding text where I did not intend to, it can be quite frustrating.

Comment: you can disable the combinations that causes the problem via the  keys bindings file

Answer (score 8):

If you have multiple cursors just press ESC to return to a single one.

---

@starwed - how did you accidentally enable it?

- Open your preferences/keymap and
- search for `split_selection_into_lines`, `find_under_expand` and `find_under_expand_skip` (these are the main methods to enable multiple cursors)
- then assign a key combination that you are unlikely to press by accident.

Comment: The problem is *accidentally* entering the mode and not noticing.

Comment: @starwed Well how did you accidentally enter the mode?  ctrl+shift+L accidentally?  multiple ctrl+Ds ?

Comment: @barlop I actually don't know!  That's part of what makes it so frustrating.

Comment: @starwed I just found that ctrl+left click can set it off(which I don't have an issue either). Maybe sometimes you click while inadvertently having a hand pushing ctrl down.

Comment: Oh. Thank. Heavens. I use a tablet in mouse mode and sublime just looses its bananas thinking every other press is a multi select. So annoying. Thanks for this.

Comment: could be his thumb touches the touchpad when he hits ctrl. or something touchpad related, or as suggested, tablet related, where touch is click.

Answer (score 4):

According to   [this link on sublime forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13518), you can't directly but you can disable the keys that trigger it.

ctrl-shift-l (that's el)
and ctrl-left click

To disable ctrl-shift-l  I don't know whether it's possible in the user file(the keymap/bindings file in the user directory), but you can in the default bindings file(the keymap/bindings file in the default directory) .. either removing the line or rewriting it e.g. adding +u
preferences..packages

`C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Default\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap`

Change this line adding a +u so it'd get triggered by ctrl+shift+l+u rather than ctrl+shift+l. I doubt you would accidentally do ctrl+shift+l+u or at least not as often as you might accidentally do ctrl+shift+l !

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+l+u"], "command": "split_selection_into_lines" },
```

Also, to disable the ctrl-left click, that link suggests doing this, and I tried it and it works. (though I I like the feature and the binding!)

Preferences..browse packages..User
`C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\user`

Create this file there, in the form `Default (<your OS>).sublime-mousemap`
Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap

it corresponds to the file of the same name in the default directory. but is in the user directory and takes precedence, overwriting settings in the default directory one.

(settings in the user directory one will take precedence and overwrite settings in the one in the Default directory)  `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` )

So, in  `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\user\Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap`

paste

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select"
    }
]
```

that disables ctrl-left click trigger of multiple selection.

Note- I use ctrl and left click, and don't recall if I have triggered it accidentally, but perhaps your thumb is touching the touchpad sometimes(making a left click) when you hit ctrl.

Comment: It works also on Linux! Thanks a lot. In my case the file is ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Default\ \(Linux\).sublime-mousemap

Answer (score 3):

in your config `Preferences -> Settings - User` add line `"multi_select": false`
In the end your config should look smth like this:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/railscasts.tmTheme",
    "detect_indentation": false,
    "font_face": "Droid Sans Mono",
    "font_size": 14,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "scroll_past_end": false,
    "tab_size": 2,
  "run_on_save": true,
  "save_on_focus_lost": true,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
  "word_wrap": true,
    "multi_select": false
}
```

I was looking how to disable that feature myself... found nothing, and just thought to play around with config... on linux it worked!

Comment: dev channel build 2220 on xubuntu 12.10. "Selection" menu now has only  "single select esc" option. multi select is switched off. sorry that on mac it doesn't work!

Comment: I tried this out on the second machine... build & system is the same.. but multiselect is still possible :( So after all this isn't appropriate method!

Comment: this didn't work for me in windows. Where on earth did you find an option called mluti_select?  i'm no sublime expert, but I thought all the options are in the default settings file, I looked there and there is no multi_select option. So no big surprise i suppose that it didn't work in the user file. Maybe it does exist.. but where did you read about that option? anyhow, I tried it, it definitely didn't work.  (though I don't want to disable it). BTW this thread says you can't disable it http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=51986